# How to detect that the phone (WP7) has stopped shaking

Tags: windows-phone-7, accelerometer, shake

I can get the phone to react to a shake, but what is the best way to tell that it has stopped shaking?

Answer (score 2):

This [example](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2010/10/24/shake-that-windows-phone-7-and-detect-it/) worked for me.

At the very bottom of the page you'll see:

```
                if (!_shaking && CheckForShake(_lastReading, reading, ShakeThreshold) && _shakeCount >= 1)
                {
                    //We are shaking
                    _shaking = true;
                    _shakeCount = 0;
                    OnShakeDetected();
                }
                else if (CheckForShake(_lastReading, reading, ShakeThreshold))
                {
                    _shakeCount++;
                }
                else if (!CheckForShake(_lastReading, reading, 0.2))
                {
                    _shakeCount = 0;
                    _shaking = false;
                }
```

Comment: The sample is generating an "Invalid cross-thread access" in the ReadingChanged method.  There is a catch which has a comment "ignore errors" but this error stops any code from executing.

Answer (score 0):

Do like #Daniel Pereira said, but in the void ShakeDetected(object sender, EventArgs e) use a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => youMethod()); and do what you pretend to do in youMethod(). I know this post is a little old but now other people can know how it resolve